# How to mock non installed library in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

**Important** **detail**: there is a library import, but the library is not installed, so the usual run will return `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somemodule'`.

We have to mock it somehow assuming we can't add new files or edit the `tested.py` file

```
# tested.py
from somemodule import somelogger


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = somelogger()

    def do_smth(self, message):
        self.logger.log(message)
```

As the module `somemodule` doesn't exist usual solutions like @patch don't suit.

I need to mock `somemodule` `somelogger's` method `log` to make it perform simple print:

```
#tests.py
from tested import MyClass


def test_logging():
    obj = MyClass()
    obj.do_smth('some_message')
```

In console:

```
some_message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
#tests.py

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock


class MockedSomelogger(object):
    def log(self, msg):
        print(msg)


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.logger_mock = MagicMock()
        self.logger_mock.somelogger = MockedSomelogger
        modules = {
            'somemodule': self.logger_mock,
        }
        self.module_patcher = patch.dict('sys.modules', modules)
        self.module_patcher.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.module_patcher.stop()

    def test_logging(self):
        # Import has to be inside the test case
        from tested import MyClass
        obj = MyClass()
        obj.do_smth('some_message')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this would be to use the `unittest.mock.patch` method as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

In your tests.py file, create a mocked log method to do the print.

```
# tests.py
from tested import MyClass
from unittest.mock import patch

def mocked_log(log_msg):
    print(log_msg)

@patch('tested.somelogger.log')
def test_logging(mock_logger)
    mock_logger.return_value = mocked_log

    obj = MyClass()
    obj.do_smth('some message')
```

Comment: have you tried this example? What version of python?

Comment: This is for python 3.6. I have done similar mocking in more complex systems and everything worked fine. If you use 2.7.x then mock needs to be installed first and you'd need to import mock instead of unittest.mock.

Comment: Sorry i missed one crucial detail: module somemodule **isn't** **suppose** **to** **exist**. So when we try to import it, we always get  ImportError: No module named **somemodule**